# literally printing integers with leading 0s

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

I am trying to print digits like 0101.... 1231, where first two digits are months and next two are days. I did this:

```
int d, m;
for (m = 01; m <= 12; m++)
    for (d = 01; d <= 31; d++)
        Console.WriteLine(loc + m.ToString() + d.ToString());
//      Directory.CreateDirectory(loc + m.ToString() + d.ToString());
```

This is printing digits like 11 instead of 0101. How can I print integers 1 through 9 as 01-09?

Comment: Keep in mind that there is no difference between `01` and `1`.  Both are simply integer constants with the value 1.  The leading zeros are not part of the value.

Comment: I know, that's why it didn't work. otherwise, if 0 was the part of 1, it would have worked as I intended.

Comment: but prize goes to MS intellisense, m(dot)tos(space)('('')'); never let me see other overloads. or I was blind. thanks anyway for not down voting. it was CS101.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
Console.WriteLine(loc + m.ToString("D2") + d.ToString("D2"));
```

See [Standard Numeric Format Strings [MSDN]](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k.aspx) for reference.

Although:

```
        var date = new DateTime(2011, 1, 1);
        while (date < new DateTime(2012, 1, 1))
        {
            Console.WriteLine(loc + date.ToString("MMdd"));
            // ^ MMdd stands for Month-Month, day-day (indicating you want them both displayed in a double digit format)
            // (uppercase M is used because lowercase m is already taken, it stands for minutes)
            date = date.AddDays(1);
        }
```

would give you more convenient control over output date format, and help you to avoid printing out dates that do not exist (such as 31 Apr or 30 Feb)

See [DateTime.ToString Method (String) [MSDN]](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zdtaw1bw.aspx) for reference.

Comment: +1 for understanding that problem is about date and giving beautiful and more intuitive code.

Answer (score 2):

```
ToString("D2")
```

This will give you the integer with two digits. Change the number for more digits.

Answer (score 2):

Use `String.Format()` method.

```
Console.WriteLine(string.Format("{0:00}{1:00}", m, d));
```